# How to compute the yield to maturity on a zero-coupon 3 year bond in this case?

Tags: bond, arbitrage, bond-yields, present-value

Suppose I have the following problem:

> We have data on three bonds: a one-year zero-coupon bond (bond A), a twoyear zero-coupon bond (bond B), and a three-year bond with an annual coupon equal to 5% of its face value (bond C). All three bonds have face values of 100 USD. The price of bond A is $90, the price of bond B is 85 USD, and the price of bond C is 105 USD.

Suppose I want to solve the following question:

> What are the price and yield of a three-year zero-coupon bond with face value of 100 USD?

I approached this problem in the following way:

By non-arbitrage, the first coupon must be worth $4.5$ since the 1 period bond with $100$ USD as face value costs 90. The second coupon must cost $4.25$ by the same reason. Then, the price of a zero coupon bond *with face value 105* should be the price of bond C less the present value of coupons: $105 - 4.5 - 4.25 = 96.25$.

Now, by non-arbitrage again, the price of a zero coupon bond with 3 years to maturity with 100 face value should be:

$$P = \frac{100}{105}\cdot 96.25 \approx 91.6667$$

The yield should be

$$ytm = \left(\frac{100}{91.97}\right)^{1/3} - 1 \approx 2.9\%$$

Is this correct? Does this make sense? Thanks!

Comment: I see some problems with your problem in that it's misisng some important details. The instructor who gave you this problem is being sloppy. Do the yields of the zero-coupon bonds use a compounding frequency? Does the yield of the coupon-paying bond use a compounding frequency? What is the frequency?

Comment: @DimitriVulis thanks for the answer! The yields of the zero-coupon bonds are compounded once a year. The coupons are paid all at once at the end of the year.